# What is the best way to code when doing GET and POST in C# Console App?

Tags: c#, post, get, console-application, .net-4.7.2

I am a beginner to GET and POST. I apologize if the question sounds stupid. But I need your help in guiding me to do it the correct way.

I have to periodically do GET from server A indefinitely until user terminate using `Ctrl + C`

To check at interval I use the timer below

```
Timer timer = new Timer(RunTask, null, 3000, 3000);
```

Where RunTask is the callback method consists of GET method to retrieve data below

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(urlA);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseBody);
}
```

Then register the data to server B through POST method

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootIssue);
    var output = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var result = await client.PostAsync(urlB, output);
    string response = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Once registered, server B will return with updated info which I have to  POST back to server A

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootIssue);
    var output = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var result = await client.PostAsync(urlA, output);
    string response = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

My question here is, what is the best approach for me to do all these queries in my console app? Should I separate each GET and POST to these

```
GetFromA()
PostToB()
PostToA()
```

I am concerned if I do it this way, is it possible that `PostToB()` will POST with incomplete response from `GetFromA()`?

Or should I combine GET and POST from A to B in one method to something like

```
GetFromAPostToB()
```

I hope that someone can point me in the correct direction.

Thanks.

Comment: you can await the GET response from a and then do the POST to B What is the exact problem?

Comment: `string response = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` - Why don't you await this, too? Why do you create 3 HttpClients? Why do think you could post an "incomplete response"? And lastly: You don't need `PostToA` and `PostToB`. All that's different is the url.

Comment: @J.Salas wouldn't the result not yet received from GET won't be ready for POST if I do it right away?

Comment: @Fildor I want something like result from GET to be used in POST before the next interval of GET is done the POST again. `string response = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` this I believe will wait for all result before set into variable. I was worried with the timer it will do POST on the same data over and over.

Comment: OK, I see. There seems to be a misconception of how async works. If you `await` you will get the "complete" result, when it is finished. If you use `.Result`, too but with the danger of a deadlock. If you want to make sure, your timer does not trigger a new "run" before the previous one has finished, you could use a bool to skip starting the run or in the run you disable the timer as first instruction and enable it again as last instruction. (Just two of many possible ways to ensure that)

Comment: @Fildor Thank you! That was very helpful. I did some more reading as well and it also led me similar to your answer as well regarding both the complete result and also how to ensure to stop the next before the current one completes.